# Card image segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection, image-segmentation

I have a dataset of images with a single rectangular (credit) card in the middle. My goal is to filter out the pixels of the card.
I would say the particular difficulties of this task are that the cards are always different (the only constant is the size proportions -54mm by 86mm-), oriented differently and the background is rather noisy.
The things I think could be exploited are that there is always a single card, in the middle of the image, and there is always a hand holding the card from an edge.

I first tried using Canny edge detector techniques which didn't yield very good results.

I then tried labelling by hand 100 images and implemented and trained a UNet with the resulting masked dataset. This did not really work well either.

Which technique do you think would make more sense in this particular case?

The idea I'm thinking about now is to exploit the fact that there is a single card, and try detecting 2 couples of parallel lines, do you think I could exploit the labeled dataset to train a model on predicting this? Ideally inputing an image and outputting 4 px-coordinates. Would this make sense?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Comment: Sorry, where do you think should i redirect this question? ^^

Comment: Check the NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).